# In what situations lists in F# are optimized by the compiler?

Tags: list, optimization, f#

In what situations lists in F# are optimized by F# compiler to arrays, to for-loops, while loops, etc. without creating actual list of single linked data?

For example:

```
[1..1000] |> List.map something
```

Could be optimized to for-loop without creating actual list. But I don't know if the compiler is doing that actually.

Mapping over lists that are less in size could be optimized with loop-unfolding, etc.

Comment: If you'd like that kind of optimization wouldn't it make more sense using a `seq` rather than leaving it to compiler's mercy?

Comment: Yes, but it should be smart enough to do it. Similar to Haskell compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In what situations lists in F# are optimized by F# compiler to arrays, to for-loops, while loops, etc. without creating actual list of single linked data?

Never.

Your later comments are enlightening because you assume that this is a flaw in F#:

> ...it should be smart enough to do it. Similar to Haskell compiler...

Somewhat true.

> ...Haskell compiler is doing a lot of such optimizations...

True.

However, this is actually a really bad idea. Specifically, you are pursuing optimizations when what you really want is performance. Haskell offers lots of exotic optimizations but its performance characteristics are actually really bad. Moreover, the properties of Haskell that make these optimizations tractable require massive sacrifices elsewhere:

- Purity makes interoperability much harder so Microsoft killed Haskell.NET and Haskell lives on only with its own incompatible VM.
- The GC in Haskell's VM has been optimized for purely functional code at the expense of mutation.
- Purely functional data structures are typically 10× slower than their imperative equivalents, sometimes asymptotically slower and in some cases there is no known purely functional equivalent.
- Laziness and purity go hand-in-hand ("strict evaluation is a canonical side effect") and laziness not only massively degrades performance but makes it wildly unpredictable.
- The enormous numbers of optimizations added to Haskell in an attempt to combat this poor performance (e.g. strictness analysis) render performance even less predictable.
- Unpredictable cache behaviour makes scalability unpredictable on multicores.

For a trivial example of these optimizations not paying off look no further than the idiomatic 2-line quicksort in Haskell which, despite all of its optimizations, remains thousands of times slower than Sedgewick's quicksort in C. In theory, a sufficiently smart Haskell compiler could optimize such source code into an efficient program. In practice, the world's most sophisticated Haskell compilers cannot even do this for a trivial two-line program much less real software.

The source code to the Haskell programs on [The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/) provide some enlightening examples of just how horrific Haskell code becomes when you optimize it.

I want a programming language to:

- Have a simple method of compilation that keeps performance predictable.
- Make it easy to optimize by hand where optimization is required.
- Have a high ceiling on performance so that I can get close to optimal performance when necessary.

F# satisfies these requirements.

Comment: Haskell.NET was basically a Master's project out of the University of Canterbury, as far as I know, how did Microsoft kill it?

Comment: AFAIK some people at MS Research Cambridge pursued the idea further but gave up when it became apparent that .NET interop is not so valuable with Haskell because almost every function relies upon side effects. Don Syme touched upon this in one of his video interviews.

Answer (score 9):

I think "never" is the answer.

Comment: It'll be pitty! Haskell compiler is doing a lot of such optimizations.

Comment: It's a whole lot easier to do optimizations for an effect-free language, I imagine!

Comment: I think improving GC from CLR side is the solution. I have also heard that JVM's GC is kind-of good at these short-time small objects while .Net's isn't.

Comment: Yes, @Brian but this is obvious case with the example above. And I believe that F# compiler is doing side-effects analysis so it knows which part of the code has no side-effects for sure.

Comment: No, I don't know of any side-effect analysis in any .NET compiler.

Comment: @YinZhu: "I think improving GC from CLR side is the solution". A better GC could certainly help because .NET will currently allocate into gen0, fill a remembered set, evacuate from gen0 to gen1 and repeat if these lists are long but I don't think GC is the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to see if you look at the disassembly - which is quite easy to read

```
    // method line 4
    .method public static
           default void main@ ()  cil managed
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2078
    .entrypoint
    // Code size 34 (0x22)
    .maxstack 6
    IL_0000:  newobj instance void class Test2/clo@2::'.ctor'()
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0007:  ldc.i4 1000
    IL_000c:  call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators/OperatorIntrinsics::RangeInt32(int32, int32, int32)
    IL_0011:  call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators::CreateSequence<int32> (class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
    IL_0016:  call class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<!!0> class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule::ToList<int32> (class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
    IL_001b:  call class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<!!1> class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule::Map<int32, int32> (class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!!0,!!1>, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<!!0>)
    IL_0020:  pop
    IL_0021:  ret
    } // end of method $Test2::main@

  } // end of class <StartupCode$test2>.$Test2
}
```

You can see that at `000c` and `0011` the enumerable is created,  and then at `0016` the sequence is converted to a list

So in this case the optimisation doesn't happen.  In fact it would be very hard for the compiler to make such an optimisation as there could be any number of differences between `Seq.Map` and `List.Map` (which is the simplest optimisation as it would avoid the temporary list).

Comment: Great, but are there some situations where lists are optimized (in Release mode with optimizations)?

Comment: @The_Ghost - Brain is on the compiler team, so if he says that it never happens, it never happens, I was just expanding on the answer and showing how you could directly check a specific instance

Comment: "which is the simplest optimisation as it would avoid the temporary list". But it isn't necessarily faster because `seq` have huge overheads.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this question was asked some time ago, the current situation is somewhat different.

Many of the list module functions do actually use an array internally.

For example, the current implementation of pairwise is

```
    [<CompiledName("Pairwise")>]
    let pairwise (list: 'T list) =
        let array = List.toArray list
        if array.Length < 2 then [] else
        List.init (array.Length-1) (fun i -> array.[i],array.[i+1])
```

also `FoldBack` (although only for lists with length greater than 4)

```
    // this version doesn't causes stack overflow - it uses a private stack 
    [<CompiledName("FoldBack")>]
    let foldBack<'T,'State> f (list:'T list) (acc:'State) = 
        let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
        match list with 
        | [] -> acc
        | [h] -> f.Invoke(h,acc)
        | [h1;h2] -> f.Invoke(h1,f.Invoke(h2,acc))
        | [h1;h2;h3] -> f.Invoke(h1,f.Invoke(h2,f.Invoke(h3,acc)))
        | [h1;h2;h3;h4] -> f.Invoke(h1,f.Invoke(h2,f.Invoke(h3,f.Invoke(h4,acc))))
        | _ -> 
            // It is faster to allocate and iterate an array than to create all those 
            // highly nested stacks.  It also means we won't get stack overflows here. 
            let arr = toArray list
            let arrn = arr.Length
            foldArraySubRight f arr 0 (arrn - 1) acc
```

Here, `foldArraySubRight` actually uses an iterative loop to process the array.

Other functions with similar optimisations include almost anything with a name like `*Back` as well as all the `sort*` functions and the `permute` function.